# How to throw a specific Exception in Julia

Tags: exception, julia

I am doing test driven development in Julia.
The test expects a certain exception to be thrown.
How do I throw the expected exception?

I'm looping through a string and counting the occurrence of specific letters.
Any letter than 'A','C','G',or'T' should result in an exception

Running Julia version 1.2.0.

I have tried these alternatives:

- `throw(DomainError())`
- `throw(DomainError)`
- `throw("DomainError")`

I expected those to work based on this resource:
https://scls.gitbooks.io/ljthw/content/_chapters/11-ex8.html

Here is a link to the problem I am trying to solve:
https://exercism.io/my/solutions/781af1c1f9e2448cac57c0707aced90f

(Heads up: That link may be unique to my login)

My code:

```
function count_nucleotides(strand::AbstractString)

    Counts = Dict()
    Counts['A'] = 0
    Counts['C'] = 0
    Counts['G'] = 0
    Counts['T'] = 0

    for ch in strand
        # println(ch)
        if ch=='A'
            Counts['A'] += 1
            # Counts['A'] = Counts['A'] + 1
        elseif ch=='C'
            Counts['C'] += 1
        elseif ch=='G'
            Counts['G'] += 1
        elseif ch=='T'
            Counts['T'] += 1
        else
            throw(DomainError())
        end
    end

    return Counts
end
```

The test:

```
@testset "strand with invalid nucleotides" begin
    @test_throws DomainError count_nucleotides("AGXXACT")
end
```

My error report, see the lines with: Expected and Thrown.

```
strand with invalid nucleotides: Test Failed at /Users/username/Exercism/julia/nucleotide-count/runtests.jl:18
  Expression: count_nucleotides("AGXXACT")
    Expected: DomainError
      Thrown: MethodError
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /Users/shane/Exercism/julia/nucleotide-count/runtests.jl:18
 [2] top-level scope at /Users/juliainstall/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Test/src/Test.jl:1113
 [3] top-level scope at /Users/username/Exercism/julia/nucleotide-count/runtests.jl:18
Test Summary:                   | Fail  Total
strand with invalid nucleotides |    1      1
ERROR: LoadError: Some tests did not pass: 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 errored, 0 broken.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `MethodError` comes from the call to `DomainError` -- there are no zero-argument constructor for this exception type. From the docs:

```
help?> DomainError

  DomainError(val)
  DomainError(val, msg)

  The argument val to a function or constructor is outside the valid domain.
```

So there are one constructor which takes the value that was out of the domain, and one that, in addition, takes an extra message string. You could e.g. do

```
throw(DomainError(ch))
```

or

```
throw(DomainError(ch, "this character is bad"))
```

Comment: Perfect! I went with `throw(DomainError(ch, "expects A,C,G, or T"))` and it works great. Thanks also for the handy pointer to the system help, I will check that out in the future. Thanks to fredrikekre an excellent person :).

Comment: Linking the docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#Exception-Handling